# dented plotting

Tags: plot

Please consider the following code

```
\draw [domain=0:10, smooth,ultra thick,yscale=100] plot (\x,{(\x^2)*(0.2*(1-0.33*\x+0.3*\x^(2))*e^(-2*\x/3))^2});
```

the last part of the plot is not smooth but dented. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu, /pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
\draw[domain=0:10, smooth, ultra thick, yscale=100] plot (\x,{(\x^2)*(0.2*(1-0.33*\x+0.3*\x^(2))*e^(-2*\x/3))^2});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Smooth bell shaped curve]

Comment: Can you please add an explanation about `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu, /pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}` to complete your answer. thank you